# Environment variable

Tags: windows, windows-7, environment-variables

I'm using setx to set a Environment variable.

My command is

```
setx -m PSR_NLC_FILE "%PROGRAMFILES(x86)%\Test Folder\"
```

But when i check on my system is set to

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Test Folder"
```

The path is not found because of the quote.

When i use this command for another Environment variable is set correct without quote.

```
setx -m PSR_NLC_FILE "%PROGRAMFILES(x86)%\Test Folder\File.lic"
C:\Program Files (x86)\Test Folder\File.lic
```

Can someone explain to me what i'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look [here](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-esc.html)

Some commands (e.g. REG and FINDSTR) use the standard escape character of \ (as used by C, Python, SQL, bash and many other languages.)
The \ escape can cause problems with quoted directory paths that contain a trailing backslash because the closing quote " at the end of the line will be escaped \".

In your case another backslash should do the trick

`setx -m PSR_NLC_FILE "%PROGRAMFILES(x86)%\Test Folder\\"`

Answer (score 1):

Don't provide the trailing backslash in your command. It's not necessary for the path name to be interpreted correctly.

The modified command would look like this:

```
setx -m PSR_NLC_FILE "%PROGRAMFILES(x86)%\Test Folder"
```